# How to get started with drawing robot

Tags: point-cloud-library, ros, realsense, moveit

I am a beginner to robotics, and I wanted to program a robot arm to draw a picture on arbitrary objects I present to him.

I do have an Intel Realsense camera, will receive a dobot.cc robot arm next days, and thought about using ROS as a base, moveit for movements and the PCL library for object detection.

How do I connect all of these together? Are there any particulary interesting tutorials that you would recommend? Anything I should try out up front?

Also, I suppose I will need to build custom code for detecting the target object in the point cloud and calculate how the picture should be placed on the object and then use moveit to follow the target path. Where would this code go?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks, 
Gregor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile, I found an excellent book on the topic:

http://www.amazon.de/Learning-ROS-Robotics-Programming-Second/dp/B00YSIL6VM/